# Options for adding WEP / WPA to my home network

Tags: networking, wireless-networking

Recently I had to upgrade my router with my ISP. When I got home I was shocked to discover that WEP / WPA features were removed, and I need them for my courses in wireless hacking.

1. My home phone is attached to Xfinity, therefore I'm locked into this current router and at this point in time I'm not ready for self-managing 3rd party Comcast approved router.
2. Can I put a router behind my ISP's router? Like this is a very cheap router available through Amazon: TP-Link N300 Wireless Wi-Fi Router - 2 x 5dBi High Power Antennas, Up to 300Mbps (TL-WR841N). Would I have access to TP-Link Admin page, i.e, set wifi security options?
3. Are there any other alternatives available out there?

Comment: I'm not saying rid yourself of your current router.  Use the updated security on your actual home connection and plug the second, vulnerable router in and attack it all day long without actually having it expose your actual network.

Comment: So I can put a router behind current router. That's what I had thought. thanks. Stoooopid question: I can then access vulnerable router's admin page and configure settings to my needs then?

Comment: The Wi-Fi Alliance banned WEP and WPA-TKIP in 2013. You’ll need to find something older than that or doesn’t use the Wi-Fi logo and trademarks.

Comment: Plug it in, connect to it over default IP after you reset it to factory (don't forget to temporarily change your IP).  Set it up the way you want it, connect back to your normal net and attack it like it was another random nearby connection you were trying to access.

Comment: Why do you need to connect the vulnerable router to your network? Why not set it up as a second isolated network?